# How Can I sign My QML plugins and Check them?

Tags: c++, plugins, qml, sign

I wrote a QML plugin and now i want to check its integrity with digital signage in other to forbid replacement and possible man in the middle attacks.

how is it possible?

Comment: As I know there are no standard ways provided for this. You can use some common way to sign your application, pgp, hashes etc. But so this question doesn't relate to Qt/QML

Comment: qt/qml should provide a mechanism to check library integrity.if it doesn't provide such a mechanism every body can compromise libraries!!!